# Finding a sufficient condition for a set to be finitely decomposable into open sets..

Tags: general-topology

Let us call a set in a topological space finitely decomposable set (FDS) iff it can be rewritten using the standard set operations $\cup$ and $\sim$ and only *finitely* many open sets.

I'm looking for a sufficient condition (a full characterisation would be even better of course) for a set to be FDS.

Open and closed sets are obviously FDS. So the characterisation is only interesting for sets which are neither open nor closed.

My idea was to prove that every set x such that:

1. Int(x) = Int(Cl(x))
2. Cl(x) = Cl(Int(x))

is FDS (I know that these can not be necessary conditions).

But I can't find an idea for a proof. Of course I'm not even sure that this works. Naturally I'm also very open to hear other suggestions for conditions.

Comment: I'm not optimistic, but it sounds interesting.

Comment: Is $\sim$ the complement operation?

Comment: Also, your conditions are not true for any single point set $\{x\}$ which is closed but not open. (Condition 2 with the point $x$, and number 1 with the complement $X\setminus x$)

Comment: Also, the open right-half plane together with rational points on the $y$-axis is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying both (1) and (2) which is not FDS. So it looks like your conditions are unnecessary and insufficient.

Comment: @Arthur, yes $\sim$ is for complement. I'm talking about a sufficient condition for being FDS. So the claim was that, if a set $x$ satisfies 1 AND 2, then $x$ is FDS. Neither of the examples you gave satisfies both 1 and 2. Right?

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Any ideas for a characterisation or sufficient conditions at least?

Comment: What about imposing those two conditions to the boundary points in x, i.e. x∩∂x? It does eliminate @Mike's example however I don't know about the proof. Counterexamples are welcome once again.